# Add bounty similar way can we not have Add money?

Tags: feature-request

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Offering actual money as a bounty?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25615/offering-actual-money-as-a-bounty)

Sometimes it looks like my answer is available but for some reason its not getting answered, even someone knows it.

Would that be possible to pay for a answer? Like add bounty another button "award 100 usd"
- because those who asked the question its sometimes very important for him, if he can get really a perfect and best answer. 
- it makes it more quality answer platform

Thanks

Comment: This has been discussed before: [Offering actual money as a bounty?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25615/offering-actual-money-as-a-bounty)

Comment: Aw, you beat me to it by _one second_, @Eat!

Comment: Appreciate it. Nice to know we are in good community, nobody can buy with money.

Comment: If you'd like to pay to play, you might be more interested in http://experts-exchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

0_0  WOW is that a bad idea.  Not only does it give idiot managers the idea that they can replace one or two (or a bunch) of developers by paying for answers to SO questions, but the brain boggles at the army of lawyers and accountants that it would take to keep such a system running.

If, for some god-awful reason, either Joel or Jeff is seriously considering this idea, then I want all of my StackExchange accounts deleted.  Now.

Comment: Your answer makes no sense at all.  If they're getting the answers now for free, why would "idiot managers" start replacing programmers only if we gave them the chance to start paying for answers?  Also, it doesn't take an army of lawyers and accountants to run [Elance](http://www.elance.com/).