# Question contains offer to pay cash for correct answer - is this okay?

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Offering actual money as a bounty?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25615/offering-actual-money-as-a-bounty)

In the text of [Htaccess Redirect / RedirectMatch subfolder does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8245517/212218), the OP offers to pay $50 for a correct answer:

> To whoever can help me solve this problem I’m willing to pay $50 and transfer the money to your paypal account.

I noticed that there is a [generally unfavorable attitude towards the idea of offering money for answers on SO](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/25615/164291), but I didn't know if it would be appropriate/policy to remove the text in question.

Thoughts?

Comment: @ChrisF that one doesn't ask what to do when you see it.

Comment: Flag it for moderator attention, or edit out the offer yourself.

Comment: Got a mod to say 'remove it'; guess that's what I was looking for (:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My inclination (without reviewing FAQs and other documents) would be to flag it and let a Stack Exchange employee make that call.

Although I see that someone has edited the question to remove the offer and posted a comment explaining why.  That's cool too.

Anyway, there are a lot of potential factors at play here.  Given the existence of the Careers site, for example, this might be seen as a way to bypass giving Stack Exchange their fee for Careers listings or whatever.  (Or not.  I'm just spinning a scenario here.)

In addition to flagging it, you might also consider leaving a comment telling the questioner that offering money like that probably has the opposite effect of what they're trying to achieve. It probably repels the people he'd want answering the question and encourages people who don't have good answers to post them anyway.  Of course, for the post you're talking about, someone has already done that.  Woot woot.