# Why was my question deleted? ... because I offered payment?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, specific-question, deleted-questions

Re: Adding Delay to Animate a hover with jQuery

I posted a question, https://stackoverflow.com/posts/13210250/revisions, and I received a notice it was edited, but I don't know why. The inbox notice shows only "Unclear as to what your question is. It seems that your question is the same as the one you'r..."

I read the guidelines, it wasn't answered, and as per the guidelines I didn't want to change the direction of an existing topic, so I posted [a new topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4247772/can-i-use-delay-together-with-animate-in-jquery).

In short, my question was how to add a hover-delay to a [jQuery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JQuery) snippet I found online (and I gave that [URL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Locator)) and posted one possible solution, a snippet there that might do that job, and I offered US$10 for the solution, because my use is for a commercial website and fair is fair.

Comment: Hi, your readiness to pay for a solution is appreciated, but Stack Overflow is not a place for paid jobs. Questions are expected to be self-contained, speficic technical questions, while yours is merely a job description. That's likely why it was closed. (Don't sweat the downvotes here on Meta, see http://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq#vote-differences)

Comment: Your question was closed as "not constructive." [Read the FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#close). There are bigger problems with your question than just offering payment for a solution (which is also [frowned upon](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25615/offering-actual-money-as-a-bounty))

Comment: @Null meh, it's a small job. I'm sure there are people who'd be willing to put in a half hour's work for a tenner. (It's still not okay to do on SO, of course)

Comment: I've undeleted your question to give you an opportunity to edit it into shape.

Comment: Ok, I'd like to edit it into shape but I don't see how to get it to. The original link is still not working. 

As for 'not constructive' I guy who worked on it for me said he invested about six hours and thought it would take a half hour. So I have to believe a solution could save many folks much time.

As for payment, this is for use on a commercial site and the generous soul need not accept it (or can give it to a charity/cause). The site or business wasn't mentioned and, also, I did check the FAQ and didn't see any notes about payment.

Comment: @user1796626 - If you want to donate $10 to charity, donate $10 to charity. Stack Overflow isn't the place for that kind of material.

Comment: Thanks Pekka. Your diplomacy is appreciated.

Comment: Personally, I think that a $10.- offer is an insult. My clients pay me way more than that so I spend my work time working for them. Then, on my free time, I answer questions in SO because I like helping the community, not for money but for pleasure.

Comment: I guess there's no easy answer to that. Damned if you do...

Perhaps many of the questions here entwined with commercial endeavors. As for the insult I wish you wouldn't feel that way as I don't know you ... it's not like you presented yourself at an interview and was offered 1/100th your value.

Answer (score 11):

I downvoted your question. I had the intention of going back to vote to close it later if no changes had been made but apparently someone got there before me. I downvoted for the following reasons:

- It's fairly difficult to understand what exactly you're after. Your title makes it quite clear and then you go and confuse, to my mind (don't forget this is just me), it in the question.
- There's no evidence you've tried anything yourself. You seem to effectively be asking for someone to provide the code for you.
- It *appears* as though you're just linking to two sites and expecting everyone to click through. Like [link only answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72000/should-there-be-a-policy-about-one-link-only-answers) questions which rely on links to make sense aren't that great; the link might be removed, which makes the question meaningless. It also involves an extra click for most people which makes it less likely they'll interact positively with the question. They won't necessarily know what's being asked.

  It's worth pointing out that when copying from a link ensure that it's licensed under Creative Commons, or that you've asked the blog authors permission. In your case you just want code that you're almost certain to be able to find on Stack OVerflow.

  There's no indication that the second site is a Stack Overflow link. It appears to be a third party site.

- Someone commented:

  > It seems that your question is the same as the one you're linking to,
  >   which would make this a duplicate and result in it being closed. Might
  >   be worth a quick edit if I've misunderstood

  You didn't acknowledge this, respond to it or edit your post. You've acknowledged it in your post here but don't seem to have looked at your post to see that it's there not just in your inbox.

  As Yoda pointed out in the comments you may not have seen this comment as your question was deleted. However, the comment was made 25 minutes after you posted your question it was over an hour later your question got deleted.
- You're offering money. Really? I'd have downvoted without this but it put the icing on the cake.
- Lastly, I'd like to re-iterate my second point. It appears as though you are demanding someone code for you. The offer of money does not make this any more constructive. There has to be a little bit of reciprocity; you have to make an effort as well as the person who answers your question.

Your post was edited to remove the "thank you" line. There are [considered unnecessary](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts); Stack Exchange is about the information being conveyed and the people who look at your question later. Your question isn't *just* about you getting an answer (although that's obviously a part). It's about a new piece of information being accessible and the people that might help in the future.

Comment: re: acknowledging the comment, it is very likely that they never even saw the comment on the post, as it was deleted (users can't see their own deleted posts without 10k). What they're quoting from is the stub in their global inbox.

Comment: Thank you @yoda, it's something I hadn't considered so I've (slightly) updated my question. There was still a time-lag between the comment and the deletion; I would have expected the OP to look at their question a few times in the first hour it was posted.

Comment: Yes, I am requesting someone code for me because the person I hired wasn't able to implement the solution he found here. So I thought I might be able to find someone else willing to do that. (And I can't post my entire reply because of the character limit... and it won't let me answer 'in full' for an hour because my rep <10.

Comment: @user1796626 Just edit the original question into form. You're not doing yourself any favors arguing here on meta, and the longer the question stays the way it is, the more downvotes you'll get: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13210250/adding-delay-to-animate-a-hover-with-jquery