# Undelete and reopen this question, or not?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

Question in question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16091025/simulating-keydown-in-google-plus-with-a-chrome-extension

Someone just offered money to whoever solved his coding issue. The question was quickly downvoted and closed. I agree with that. The question however was not that bad, and could be salvaged by simply editing out the parts about the money offer. That's what I did, but when my edit was submitted, the post was already deleted, by a moderator. So I can't  can't even vote to undelete.

Do you agree it should have been deleted? In my opinion, now it could even be reopened.

Comment: The second paragraph is still a chore to trudge through, and the whole thing needs a coherent `tl;dr` summary, but the edits do improve it, I think.

Comment: @KnightswhosayNi So you're demanding a sacrifice? :)

Comment: @BlahBlahGrabblesnackers Agree, it was a quick edit, could have been better. But maybe that's enough for at least undeleting it.

Comment: @bfavaretto I undeleted it. Let's see where the discussion goes before we reopen, though. The question is so heavily downvoted now that even if it's reopened, it'd be at a fairly severe disadvantage.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I admittedly have no clue about the topic, but what exactly is too localized? Just the particular application scenario? Or does the whole concept have no use outside of that scenario? Merely asking because it reads like a question with some significant effort and, with the dupe now deleted as well, it feels like we might have a new user running himself into the ground here.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I'm not sure I agree with that, but I do agree with the duplicate you found. Considering the OP didn't join this discussion yet, I'd call my job with that question done. If he later shows some interest on his question and this discussion, I'm here to help.

Comment: @Bart: I think the OP might be better off looking for the Javascript code in the page that is producing the behavior he wants and trying to replicate that functionality, instead of attempting to fire phantom events which are rightly the province of the user.  In any case, I linked the OP to a duplicate question.

Comment: If someone wants to offer money let 'em, who cares, it's their money (and the answerer's risk that he chooses to take).

Comment: @LanceRoberts: [Yeah, no](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/25621).

Comment: I hope my same question asked in the link that Robert pointer do not offend anybody in the "community" since I am not offering any money. I feel like I am very unrespectfull asking help without providing anything in exchange, but it looks like everybody here in SO likes working for free and do not value the knowledge they have so I will not offer money anymore. It looks like everybody is already rich enough.

Comment: @JoãoMiros: One of the great things about Stack Overflow is that we value altruism over the almighty dollar. (Wow, that sounded *so noble,* didn't it?)

Comment: @JoãoMiros - we're here for fun.  That's one of the reasons this site is so great.  There are plenty of sites where you can "rent a coder" - this just isn't one of them

Answer (score 8):

**We do not allow offering money on questions.**

As answered by @Shog9 ♦ in a heavily downvoted Meta question about [Offering actual money as a bounty](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25615/offering-actual-money-as-a-bounty/):

> Since they really need that $20, they'll likely hang around and down-vote any other answers, while picking fights with anyone who criticizes theirs. Just look at the little fights people get into over rep now, and spice it up with some desperation.

Also, as @zpesk points out in another answer:

> Joel and Jeff talked about this on one of the podcasts... they believe offering financial incentives reinforces the wrong behavior.

**It was therefore correct for the question to be deleted.**

Comment: I disagree with the last sentence: that question could have been edited (as I did), and reopened.

Comment: @bfavaretto As Anna pointed out though; at that point, the question's already at a disadvantage by being heavily downvoted.

Comment: But that is reversible too. If it's usually not reversed, the reopening feature becomes less useful, and makes me think the system is broken.

Answer (score -4):

I offered money cause I believe it's more than fair give money to a person that helped me solving a problem. It's really fair. I cant see it other way.

I do not think that anybody here should work for free. NOBODY must work for free since everybody has a great knowledge and I respect that and I want to offer money for this knowledge that lacks on me.

Comment: Nobody here is being compelled to answer your question or any other. We're all here to help out where we can, and we all get something out of it without any money changing hands. It's understandable that you want to compensate people for helping you, but the way to do that here is to stick around and offer to help others where you can. That's what makes the community work. Welcome.

Comment: @Caleb  it looks like everybody here in SO likes working for free and do not value the knowledge they have so I will not offer money anymore. It looks like everybody is already rich enough

Comment: No, nobody on SO works for free. For most of the users who answer questions on Stack Exchange, answering question is not a work at all.

Comment: @JoãoMiros - look, here's the deal.  The reason SO is so successful, in my opinion and others', is because Jeff and Joel turned Q&A into a game.  And nerds love games.  If this site were one of those grimy "rent-a-coder" sites, then me and a lot of other people wouldn't be here.

Comment: @João I understand your intention was good, but that's just not how it works here. [Allowing money offers has been discussed before](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/25621), and most people thought it would be prejudicial *to the site* (of course, it could be beneficial to some individuals' bank accounts). That being said, we have rules and procedures here (well, kind of), that's why your question was downvoted, then closed. It was also deleted and I didn't agree, so I came to meta to ask about that. That's how things work here. [continues...]

Comment: ... Now, those same rules and procedures say you should not ask the same question more than once. The fact that you asked it three times bothers me (the one who originally was trying to help you, and save/undelete/reopen your question). Your third question is probably the reason the original question was deleted, again, by a moderator. My intention with this meta question was to have that reopened, and hopefully answered, instead.

Comment: @bfavaretto you are so king. Thank you all the explanation. I understand what you said but they closed/deleted my post (that I took about 20min to type) without even given a reasonable explanation or at least a chance to me fix the problem. The removed it and I lost everyhing I typed! That's what upsets me Sir. I opened another post with the same question but trying to be in your Tos, but even that people compailned about opening another... I was just trying to clear my mistake making another question with no error. You get it?