# Monetizing SE bounties?

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, bounties

I often use math.stackexchange.com and MathOverflow.net to ask questions.  However, the questions I ask typically tend to be too advanced for Math.SE but too trivial for MO.  Since typical MO questions take around 20-40 minutes to answer [for me anyways], I often get very high-quality answers on MO, and for this reason I do not wish to bother MO users unless I absolutely need something answered.

If there were a way to pay users who give good answers, I would feel less uncomfortable asking MO users my questions.  I saw [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25615/offering-actual-money-as-a-bounty) that the idea of connecting money to SE has been viewed very negatively.  However, none of downsides listed are something that cannot be worked around.  Here is how:

Option 1: no modifications, except:

> 0. when accepting an answer, give an option to "Send $__ to this user."

This would already be enough for me.

Option 2 would consist of the following modifications:

1. Require pre-paying bounties.
2. An answerer does not get the bounty unless manually awarded by the asker within a week [otherwise, bounty money goes to SE].

2a. When new users post questions, add a warning that these questions are answered by volunteers, not paid researchers, and that their money can be lost without an answer if their question is not formatted properly.  Sort of "You're paying for the time on Featured tab, not for the answer" philosophy.  If they don't like it, they can go to Google Answers.

3. Depening on your reputation, place a limit on the amount of monetary bounties you are allowed to place.
4. Make the minimum bounty, say, $20.  Possibly make a single forum for less-than-$20 questions, where unskilled people might go to try to earn a buck or two.  This cut-off can be adjusted for various sites (e.g. $50 for MathOverflow, vs. $5 for Math.SE)

Here is my answer to the downsides of monetizing SE:

> Guaranteed, someone, somewhere has time to burn and needs cash. No guarantee they know the answer, mind you... but they'll take a guess at it. And since they really need that $20, they'll likely hang around and down-vote any other answers, while picking fights with anyone who criticizes theirs. Just look at the little fights people get into over rep now, and spice it up with some desperation

(2) Requiring bounty award to be manually awarded would solve this problem.

Also, quoting kalenjordan's answer (which will henceforth always be denoted by fixed-point font):

```
  The link juice and traffic that SE provides currently is already a
  massive incentive for abuse, and yet they're able to handle it very well.

  The same could be said about point bounties - because they are an
  enhanced incentive they increase the potential for fraud.
```

---

> People should be motivated to answer questions because they are interested in the field, not because they are offered some money.

Depends on the field.  For example, if I remember correctly: back when I was a beginning programmer, I was writing an Android app that compiles PDF files for my math research.  I did not know how to make the native PDF Viewer app to open from within my app, so I asked this on SE, but got downvotes because the question was so basic, with links to internet sites explaining it [about half of which I tried to implement before posting the question].  Sure, it's basic, and it would take about 15 minutes to answer it; but, I spent around 18 hours already, and still haven't figured out how to do it; so every time I wish to view the PDF file I compiled I have to leave my app, go to the PDF viewer, and the close the PDF viewer, go back to my app, and reload the file I was working on.  At the time, I did not have the rep to offer a bounty on that question.  I would definitely be willing to pay even $100 for the 15-minute answer to a "basic" question.

```
 People respond to incentives. If people are supposed to answer purely
 and only because of their interest, then why have points and badges
 in the first place?
```

---

> Yeah, and after you answer, if the person refuses to pay up, Jeff and Joel should have to mediate the dispute. Or, maybe we can just migrate the question to LawyerOverflow?

(1) Requiring pre-paying bounties would solve that problem.

---

> If [an answerer] tells the [asker] the question has no definitive answer, [in cases where he's unpaid,] that response is more likely taken as fact rather than a personal failing on the [answerer]'s part
>
> In the Google Answers arena, I have seen researchers insulted, sworn at, and otherwise degraded by people not happy with the responses they received
>
> While I enjoyed my time at Google Answers, I was soured by people asking $4 questions and not being satisfied with the depth of the responses they received, responses that had clearly taken a fair amount of the researcher's time.
>
> This "customer is always right" philosophy that pervades marketplace interactions seemed to override personal senses of reasonableness in many cases.

These particular issues are motivated by users not understanding how SE works.  They just come in, and expect to pay and get what they want, not taking the extra time to get familiar with SE.  My (2a) and (3) attempt to address this issue; however, it is possible that yet another approach might be necessary to solve this particular issue.

In my suggested solution, the fact that the money has been paid even if the question gets no answers, should make the asker less inclined to be unhappy over getting a low-quality answer, because the other option would be getting no answer at all.

```
  Sure there's the possibility that the developer spends the 30 minutes
  and then the asker says they didn't feel the quality of the answer was
  high enough, and so the developer is frustrated by that. But that's an
  existing problem on the site just with the point system.

  People answer questions all the time and don't even get them marked as
  the answer or upvoted at all. There can be mechanisms to help with
  this such as the askers rate of marking a question as answered, etc.
```

---

> If the questioner offers too little, the researcher should simply refuse to answer their question. Of course, in the competition for scarce questions, this never happened, except in extreme instances.
>
> my experience working for Google Answers made me feel more often like I was being paid to do Google searches that the questioners didn't have the time or the skill to do, rather than using my research background and abilities to turn facts into actual knowledge.

(4) Setting the minimum bounty at $20 should get rid of this problem.

```
  If money was offered, it would feel like work so I wouldn't want
  to do it in my free time any more.
```

I believe that people answer $0 questions on SE already.  In my opinion, the main difference is, when askers are not paying anything, then they feel expected to put in some effort on their part.  The big downside of allowing low-value questions is that doing so would result in low-quality questions, for which people expect answers.  Moving such questions to a separate forum should free the main forums of such questions, and at the same time allow people looking to earn a buck or two, to do so without affecting their rep on the main site.

---

```
 > Why not just post the question on another freelance project site?

 You could say the same thing about SE's resume and job posting
 services. Why not just use existing services that are out there?

 The answer is that SE has an amazing community behind it. The chances
 that my question will be answered quickly and accurately are simply
 much higher on SE than basically anywhere else.
```

This definitely seems like a viable option: at least for trial on select SE sites.  Can anyone think of any major shortcomings I missed? [have to go do something now; more reasons to be added when I come back]

Comment: No amount of "working around" would ever cause us to implement real currency bounties in any form on our sites.

Comment: Is there an underlying reason?  I have over 1K rep on Math.SE, and I still fail to see why.  As mentioned above, there have been cases when I really wished at least to be able to thank the answerer more than by just upvoting and accepting the answer, and I didn't have the rep to offer a bounty.

Comment: If you have over 1K, you could easily offer a bounty of 50 rep... SE isn't a way to earn money... that's just not how it works.

Comment: @Catija I have over 1K on Math.SE where I know the material; but where I need help is SE, where my question gets dismissed as too trivial.  Being able to thank a user on a non-Math.SE site for putting in a lot of effort to answer my question would be nice.

Comment: Be patient. You'll get there. Remember, we don't come here and answer questions for rep or for money... we do it because we like answering questions... and that's how it should be. It'd be awful if people started expecting monetary rewards for their answers... which is what would happen if they were possible. You really don't want that to happen here.

Comment: Related, and possibly will explain to you why this is a bad idea: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/42481/the-problem-with-extrinsic-motivation

Comment: I hate downvoting questions which obviously show much work and thought were put into them.

Comment: @Won't I hate more when answers that are not well-thought-through get upvotes simply because.  Eg.:
`when accepting an answer, give an option "Send $__ to this user."`
> How exactly do you know where to send the money? Maybe ask them for their address or info to their PayPal account? No! No! No! I bet right now, the top users at Security.SE are scolding at this.
`Of course, the question of how to send the money can be worked out.  Use SE as escrow, or send a PayPal balance.  I mean, sure, go ahead and criticize the bad points: but at least leave the good ones be.`

Answer (score 3):

So... you here for the money or the trust funds (reputation)?

Now with this implemented, we can ensure that lots of users will take Stack Exchange as a nice, easy way to earn money instead of posting high-quality questions/answers and help improve the site as a whole. This defers from the true cause of being here at Stack Exchange which is to provide high-quality posts that can help yourself, other users, and the world because you want to. Else, Stack Overflow would be like a job, not a hobby.

> when accepting an answer, give an option to "Send $__ to this user."

How exactly do you know where to send the money? Maybe ask them for their address or info to their PayPal account? No! No! No! I bet right now, the  top users at Security.SE are scolding at this. I don't think users will want to post their rather sensitive information online just for the money... for thousands to see. Security flaws are everywhere here.

> Require pre-paying bounties... An answerer does not get the bounty unless manually awarded by the asker within a week [otherwise, bounty money goes to SE].

So where do you enter the bounty? Another flaw in the plan that requires SE to reveal their own PayPal account or something. Also, did you notice that Stack Exchange is actually non-profit?

> Depening on your reputation, place a limit on the amount of monetary bounties you are allowed to place.

Same with bounties... it's a privilege and you can only use as much rep as you currently have. Nothing that great of an improvement...

> Make the minimum bounty, say, $20. Possibly make a single forum for less-than-$20 questions, where unskilled people might go to try to earn a buck or two. This cut-off can be adjusted for various sites (e.g. $50 for MathOverflow, vs. $5 for Math.SE)

Basically you are saying that anyone that goes for a bounty less than 20 dollars is outright stupid? I don't think so. Every site and its users should be treated as equal no matter what their "skill level" is. This will prevent any discrimination and the angry users at the "lower sites".

> Requiring bounty award to be manually awarded would solve this problem.

With the cash definitely going towards someone, you solve the problem about the battles. Now you make a new one: a freaking full-scale war. The users will do anything to get the attention from serial voting to destructive edits, who knows what is next now?!

> People respond to incentives. If people are supposed to answer purely
> and only because of their interest, then why have points and badges
> in the first place?

To add more interest and addiction! It's all in the "business"! This motivates users to provide more high-quality posts in a way in which it should be fun for everyone who understands the rules. With money, SE is now an anarchy.

> Yeah, and after you answer, if the person refuses to pay up, Jeff and Joel should have to mediate the dispute. Or, maybe we can just migrate the question to LawyerOverflow?

And more disputes come up followed by lawsuits and angry users (especially at Security.SE!). So instead, let's stick to rep in which you can almost never get back okay?

> Setting the minimum bounty at $20 should get rid of this problem.

Clearly conflicts with one of your statements.

> In my opinion, the main difference is, when askers are not paying anything, then they feel expected to put in some effort on their part.

Well, why else are you here? You joined because you wanted high-quality posts from users you can trust. No wonder SE is so popular nowadays. If you can't do that, please don't post until you're ready to.

---

So in conclusion, this is a terrible idea and I would love to add [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/25621/278543) by Shog9 as it thoroughly addresses many key points about the cons of the idea:

> If I know the answer but am not willing to put the time in to answer your question for free... then I'm probably not gonna do it for $20 either.
>
> But someone will.
>
> Guaranteed, someone, somewhere has time to burn and needs cash. No guarantee they know the answer, mind you... but they'll take a guess at it. And since they really need that $20, they'll likely hang around and down-vote any other answers, while picking fights with anyone who criticizes theirs. Just look at the little fights people get into over rep now, and spice it up with some desperation...
>
> So if you just want answers, and lots of 'em, but don't really care if they actually answer the question... And if you love flame wars... Then yes, this is a great idea.
>
> If you like anything about the way the site works now, then it's a terrible idea.

Comment: ........bitcoin?