# NFT on Stack Exchange / Stack Overflow

Tags: discussion, ownership

I'm totally not an expert, but do you think it could be possible to sell an answer or question on any Stack Exchange in [NFT (non-fungible token)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-fungible_token#:%7E:text=A%20non%2Dfungible%20token%20(NFT,other%20forms%20of%20creative%20work.))?

There are a lot of question around this: how could it harm Stack Exchange in term of quality, is that in alignment with SE values, etc.

Comment: why is it necessary? all info here should be public.

Comment: The day questions and/or answer will be sold, I'm stopping all my activity on Stack Exchange network for good, and I'm 100% sure thousands of other active users will do the same. It will almost surely be the end of Stack Exchange. (Well, the sites will stay online, but become mass graveyard of questions without answers.)

Comment: @MarkKirby Right... except that at no point, this post was a feature request. It was originally tagged discussion and is now tagged support.

Comment: Just to be clear: NFT is money. Plain and simple. You can call it NFT, PGSFTRR, or anything you like, but in the end of the day, it's something someone has to buy with real money.

Comment: I should have probably not mention "sell" and only "relates to" or "can relates to", but indeed, it was only a discussion. Thanks anyway for pointing this as duplicate, I found the first [answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/25621/286468) useful, as well as the comments relating to Google Answers.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I'm unsure what the value of this would be - considering all our posts are under some variety of CC-By-SA.

By design, our answers can be shared freely (which is antithetical to something being unique) and belong to the 'commons' of the internet. With *millions* of posts - there's rarely specific answers or questions whose 'ownership' (and I'm unsure what the ownership would mean here!) would have some specific, additional value on the open market. "I own the NFT for the infamous parsing  XML with regex question!"

Then what?

In theory I guess NFTs add artificial scarcity to 'virtual' items - but outside speculators, there's literally no value in NFTs. In the case of posts here - they don't really map to virtual versions of physical objects as many NFT subjects do. Posts on a site are not collectable (unlike a physical piece of art, and an NFT as an analog to that, or a trading card and its NFT analog)...

As such, I don't particularly feel that its a logical fit for what we do here.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! It seems indeed that it doesn't fit, and there is the question on the edition by other peoples of an answer/questions too. Thanks for the clarification!

Comment: This answer actually applies to NFTs in general. NFTs aren't tokens of ownership of whatever image is attached to the NFT... It's an artificial market that trades in _literally_ nothing.